# Creating PDF in Codeigniter with Dompdf

Tags: codeigniter, pdf-generation

I am Using DomPDF for developing pdf in Codegniter GIving Error

```
require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/manisha/application/helpers/dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/classes/Font.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\manisha\application\helpers\dompdf\dompdf_config.inc.php on line 332
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your include fails. Please check the file permissions and if the "Font.php" file is actually at:

`C:/xampp/htdocs/manisha/application/helpers/dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/classes/Font.php`

Also, check if it works when you change "require_once()" into "require()", if so, you probably trying to include that file multiple times.